# SQL Server: how to avoid between operator with datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime column and I would like to select rows based on this columns. My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.mytable
WHERE  daycol BETWEEN '20110404' AND '20110406';
```

This will also brings me a row

```
2011-04-06 00:00:00.000
```

Which is not correct. How to avoid this? Should between operator be avoided with datetime columns?

Comment: Because I would like to retrieve days 20110404 and 20110405.

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive, it has nothing to do with DateTime, if you don't want that, don't use BETWEEN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `if you don't want the row of 2011-04-06 00:00:00.000 date`

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.mytable
WHERE  daycol >= '20110404' AND daycol < '20110406';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you write out this line:

```
WHERE daycol BETWEEN '20110404' AND '20110406';
```

You get:

```
WHERE '2011-04-04 00:00:00.000' <= daycol 
      and daycol <= '2011-04-06 00:00:00.000'
```

`Between` is inclusive.  If you'd like to exclude the boundaries, change `<=` to `<` in the expanded version.

Answer (score 3):

Please note this is the expected behavior of `BETWEEN` 
(See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

From the article:

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than **or equal** to the value of end_expression.

You can modify your end_expression to get different results than you are receiving.

Or use `>=`, `<` operators.  But be careful if the column you are comparing against is `DATETIME` T-SQL will convert `'20110406'` to `'2011-04-06 00:00:00.000'` so take this into consideration when determining which operators to use.